# PHP script cannot access database in sql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database through a php script. It gives me this error from `mysql_error()`: Access denied for user `'@localhost'` to database `'userinfo'`

`userinfo` is the database.

my script is this

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "'mm'";
$database = "userinfo";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

echo "Connected successfully<br>";

mysql_select_db($database) or die(mysql_error());

echo "connected successfully to db:" . $database . "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: Is your password really `'mm'` or `mm`?

Comment: i accidentally set it to 'mm'. the reason I set it to mm is bc this is my first time using it and didn't feel like making a long password.

Comment: You may have to add user privileges if you want external access to the DB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html

Comment: Are you using a hosting provider or did you setup mysql server and PHP on your own system. And if so are you using software like WAMP? I ask this because you can connect to DB's differently on hosting providers

For example on hostgaator you would connect like username_dbasenamme and with godaddy it is something like db.server.com

Comment: I set it up o my own system using xampp

Comment: I have already added permission to all users. I have read other stackoverflow questions/answers and none have worked for me.

Comment: Are you sure your password is correct? You have entered a 4-character password - `'mm'`. Did you actually set it to a 2-character `mm`? I think that was what @Chan was asking, but your reply suggested you didn't understand his question.

Comment: please read my answer. The code I used should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are connecting using

```
mysqli_
```

function
and selecting data with

```
mysql_
```

avoid using both at the same time. since they're incompatible.
use the **mysqli_** alternative instead

```
mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);
```

and

```
mysqli_error($conn)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please keep in mind this isn't the safest way. But since you have said your learning this it is a start.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "mm";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
?>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

To select data from the database

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

It appeared you where combining the old mysql in php with the new mysqli